# range() but with normal distribution? (no randomness)

Tags: python, statistics, normal-distribution

Looking for a python function that emulates range() but for a normal distribution rather than a set interval.

So instead of `range(min, max, interval)` I want something like `mynormrange(min, max, numberofpoints)`. The option to inverse the distribution would be great too.

So `mynormrange(0, 100, 9)` would output something like `[0, 34, 47.5, 49.85, 50, 50.15, 52.5, 66, 100]` where the numbers around the average (avg=50 in this case) are closer together.

And the inverse `mynormrange(0, 100, 9, inverse=True)` would output something like `[0, 0.15, 2.5, 16, 50, 84, 97.5, 99.85, 100]` where the numbers around the edges (0 and 100 in this case) are closer together.

I don't want randomness though, so random.normal() doesn't work for what I need.

Something like numpy's linspace() but for a normal distribution.

Edit: I'm just going to combine linspace and cosine multiplied by my desired max value. Sine for the inverse.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is to construct an ordinary, uniform range from 0 to 1 (e.g., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... 0.9) and then map the inverse cdf over that, which will give the quantiles of the distribution. Maybe there is a quantile function which will give that directly.

Comment: I think the inverse, as you describe it, is to map the cdf over a uniformly spaced list.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is using a truncated normal distribution to generate numbers and put two ends of the range on the list. Then, sort them in ascending order (descending for the inverse) and report it as what you desire. To draw truncated normal samples, you can use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316392/3768871).

However, it cannot be a function like `range` as it generates random results (with a specified distribution). Notice that you can put the mean for the range of `[a,b]`, `(a+b)/2`, but you need to specify the variance for the distribution (unless you define it base on the given range).

Beware that your statement about "I don't want randomness though" cannot be meaningful here! Because you are talking about a distribution!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use something like [**`np.random.normal()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).

This allows for the generation of an array of whatever shape you want.

- The first argument `loc` is the centre of your standard distribution, **`50`** in your example above.
- The second argument `scale` is the standard deviation (spread or “width”) of the distribution.
- The last argument `size` is simply the output shape which can be a number or tuple of ints

We will then use this array to sample from a distribution and [**`np.clip`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) the outputs to a min-max value (as we could get extreme values depending on our array size). Finally we sort the output prior with [**`np.sort`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.0/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)

```py
def mynormrange(min, max, stddev, numberofpoints):
    # (min+max)//2 yields the centre point of our distribution 
    distribution = np.random.normal(loc=(min+max)//2, 
                                    scale=stddev,
                                    size=numberofpoints)
    return np.sort(np.clip(distribution, min, max), axis=None)

>>> mynormrange(min=0, max=100, stddev=28, numberofpoints=20)
array([ 0.        , 11.84519127, 16.3296094 , 24.55199703, 25.30222761,
       30.46270933, 30.52531999, 34.18142498, 42.30422449, 44.8864856 ,
       48.54756954, 56.00797349, 58.51853892, 58.65086592, 61.0481076 ,
       68.87172721, 77.65995267, 85.73321417, 86.2329193 , 86.31444371])
```

As for the inverse of this... I believe you could find a similar function and use the same sampling technique as above. I will comment/edit this when/if I find that.

Let me know if this helps and if you have any questions.